# .htaccess redirect not found page to a specific page

Tags: .htaccess

Here's my code

```
RewriteRule ^error$ error.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^siteuri_partenere$ siteuri_partenere.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^politica_de_confidentialitate$ politica_de_confidentialitate.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blog - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ game.php?weblink=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /error [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So, if i change this line

```
RewriteRule . /error [L,R=302]
```

to

```
RewriteRule . /page_not_found [L,R=302]
```

and then i test www.domain.com/1q2w3e, is still redirect to /error and not to /page_not_found so i'm very confusing where is the problem?

Comment: Did you try a different browser to test?

Comment: Yes I tried + delete cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have some `ErrorDocument 404` directive that is overriding your rewrite rules. Place this code in your root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
ErrorDocument 404 default
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^error$ error.php [L]

RewriteRule ^siteuri_partenere$ siteuri_partenere.php [L]

RewriteRule ^politica_de_confidentialitate$ politica_de_confidentialitate.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+?)/?$ game.php?weblink=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /page_not_found [L,R=302]
```

Comment: still don't work, i tried on my localhost and on my webhosting, very confusing.

Comment: Does it still redirect to `/error`? What was the original URL you entered?

Comment: I tested for ex localhost/1q2w3enotexistpage and still redirect to /error

Comment: It is definitely not happening from these rules. You will have to search your code and/or Apache config to see where this redirection is happening.